# Векторизация, будет ли от неё толк в сетевом программировании?

Tags: c#, .net

Речь идёт о структуре из пространства имён 'Numerics.Vector', которая по данным с MSDN - "подходит для низкоуровневых параллельных оптимизаций". В каких именно задачах стоит ее использовать? Я по большей части пишу сетевые приложения, где оперирую массивами байт ('byte[]'). Как известно - тип byte это unsigned char из 'C++', диапазон его значений от 0 до 255 и размер 8 бит. Есть ли смысл менять массив байт на вектор, будет ли прирост производительности в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Векторизация [может ускорить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562580/10105) ваше приложение в его модельной части. Если у вас есть часть программы, занимающаяся вычислениями или другой массовой обработкой данных, то применение SIMD-операций может её существенно ускорить. (А может и не ускорить, это уж как повезёт с задачей.)

А в обыкновенном сетевом коде прироста производительности скорее всего не будет, т. к. скорость обработки обычно на порядок, а то и несколько, меньше латентности сети. Вы не выиграете ничего.

---

В любом случае, профилируйте. Гарантированно правильный ответ по поводу того, где ваша программа тормозит, даёт только профилирование. Никто здесь на сайте, не зная архитектуру вашей программы, не сможет дать конкретного дельного совета. Мы можем озвучить только общий принцип.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос продиктован чистым интересом в рациональности применения векторизация для работы с байтами в будущих проектах, отлаживать ничего не нужно.

Comment: @user222250: Пожалуйста!