# c# list фильтрация по одному полю типа String с несколькими параметрами

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, list, linq

У меня есть List, где T - объект класса со множеством полей типа String.
Мне нужно отфильтровать этот список по одному из полей объекта с учётом того что значений для фильтрации 2 и больше. 
простой способ я нашел: foreach по списку
Вопрос:

- есть ли более изящный(например через LINQ to List)?
- если список большой и полей много, что будет быстрей работать?

Comment: Если нужно реально быстро и чтобы помучиться, можно скомпилировать `Expression`, как сделано [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562688/10105). Но изящнее, чем LINQ, не получится.

Answer (score 3):

Предположим, что у Вас есть такой вот класс:

```
public class SuperClass
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
    public string Three { get; set; }
}
```

Создадим список объектов нашего класса и добавим несколько элементов:

```
var lst = new List<SuperClass>();
lst.Add(new SuperClass() { One = "1", Two = "2", Three = "3" }); // first
lst.Add(new SuperClass() { One = "11", Two = "2", Three = "33" }); // second
lst.Add(new SuperClass() { One = "111", Two = "222", Three = "3" }); // third
```

Предложу такой способ фильтрации через `LINQ` с помощью `Where`:

```
var onlyTwo = lst.Where(x => x.Two == "2");                       // first, second 
var twoAndThree = lst.Where(x => x.Two == "2" && x.Three == "3"); // first
var twoOrThree = lst.Where(x => x.Two == "2" || x.Three == "3");  // first, second, third
```

Еще можно воспользоваться методом из `List<T>`, с помощью `FindAll`:

```
var onlyThree = lst.FindAll(x => x.Three == "3"); // first, third
```

Полезные ссылки для изучения:

1. [Метод Enumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Метод List.FindAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Выражения запросов LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397676.aspx)

Относительно того, что будет быстрее: думаю, что `LINQ` будет достаточно быстрым, `FindAll` возвращает новую коллекцию, поэтому думаю, что он будет медленнее, а вот перебирать через `foreach` с внутренней проверкой и добавлением в новый список - наверняка будет самым медленным. Если я ошибаюсь в скорости, то я не против того, чтобы меня исправили. В любом случае можно всегда проверить, что будет работать быстрее.

Comment: Методы LINQ, так же как и `FindAll` вызывают делегаты - это лишние накладные расходы. Так что `foreach` или `for` будет быстрее (хотя, смотря как написать), но длиннее.

Comment: `FindAll` по своей структуре похож на `LINQ` такого вида: `Where(...).ToList()`, да и возвращается новая коллекция, поэтому предположил, что просто `Where` будет быстрее. А вот `foreach` или `for` действительно могут быть быстрее, но это зависит от того, насколько просто они написаны.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с LINQ to Objects:

```
var list = Process.GetProcesses();
var filters = new[] { "chrome", "notepad" };
var results = from item in list
              where filters.Contains(item.ProcessName, StringComparer.InvariantCulture)
              select item;
```

Быстродействие и изящность кода часто не пересекаются. Быстрее будет работать цикл `for` и хэш-таблица вместо `string[]` для фильтров, если список не очень большой. Если список большой - имеет смысл распараллелить с помощью `TPL` и `PLINQ`.

Comment: `Если список большой - имеет смысл распараллелить с помощью TPL и PLINQ` - Не могли бы вы показать как это будет выглядеть?