# C# как создать класс который бы одинаково работал с int и double?

Tags: c#

Например класс для работы с комплексными числами. Я хочу чтобы конструктор и некоторые методы могли принимать как int так и double. Внутри методов только математические операции которые выполнимы для всех числовых типов. Более расширенная версия задания, иметь возможность передавать в методы любые класы которые поддерживают математические операции.

Подскажите каким образом лучше всего это реализовать, мне на ум приходит только создание интерфейса который бы определял все операции а потом нужные класы наследовать от него, но тогда как быть с int и double?

Comment: Увы, никак. Разве что сделать кодогенерацию на T4.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Ну, возможность есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562575/10105

Comment: @VladD - действительно, про `Numerics.Vectors` я забыл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать кодогенерацию на встроенном в Visual Studio генераторе кода [T4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb126445.aspx).

Добавляем в проект Text Template (с расширением `.tt`). Пишем в нём, например, такой код:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

namespace MyApp // заменить на нужное
{
    public class Calculator
    {
    <# 
        // Добавить/удалить типы
        var types = new string[] { "int", "long", "float", "double" };

        foreach(var T in types)
        {
    #>
        public <#=T#> Add(<#=T#> a, <#=T#> b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public <#=T#> Subtract(<#=T#> a, <#=T#> b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    <#
        }
    #>
    }
}
```

Несложно заметить, что это очень похоже на Razor (веб-разработчики хорошо с ним знакомы).

`output extension` нужно заменить на `.cs` - нам нужен на выходе код C#.

Компилируем проект. Получаем класс с набором перегрузок методов.

---

Для удобной работы с T4 в Студию можно установить какое-нибудь расширение, например, tangible T4.

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, в C# нет общего типа и общего метода работы с числами *произвольного* типа. Невозможно выразить наличие статических операций сложения/вычитания при помощи ограничений на обобщённые типы (generic constraints).* Но вы можете определить нужные операции самостоятельно, например, так:

```
class Operation
{
    public static T Add<T>(T t1, T t2) => OperationImpl<T>.add(t1, t2);
    public static T Subtract<T>(T t1, T t2) => OperationImpl<T>.subtract(t1, t2);

    class OperationImpl<T>
    {
        public static Func<T, T, T> add, subtract;
        static Func<T, T, T> ForceCast<U>(Func<U, U, U> f) => (Func<T, T, T>)(object)f;

        static OperationImpl()
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            {
                add = ForceCast<int>((x, y) => x + y);
                subtract = ForceCast<int>((x, y) => x - y);
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
            {
                add = ForceCast<double>((x, y) => x + y);
                subtract = ForceCast<double>((x, y) => x - y);
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Complex))
            {
                add = ForceCast<Complex>((x, y) => x + y);
                subtract = ForceCast<Complex>((x, y) => x - y);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    $"Operations on type {typeof(T).Name} are not supported");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/XOea6Z

Альтернативные решения (использование `Expression.Compile` или `System.Numerics.Vectors`) описаны [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562575/10105).

---

*Но работа в этом направлении ведётся, [рассматривается возможность введения typeclass'ов à la Haskell](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164).

Answer (score 2):

Я тут все балуюсь с [IL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), так что мое решение напрямую связано с ним)

---

Итак. Давайте начнем вот с чего: 
Напишем такой вот код:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = a + b;
```

Просмотрев `IL`-код, созданный для данной цепочки выражений, мы увидим нечто такое:

```
ldc.i4.2    
stloc a
ldc.i4.3    
stloc b
ldloc a
ldloc b
add         
stloc c
```

*(Код примерный, таким он, конечно, не будет. Приведен он в таком виде для ясности происходящего)*

Что же отвечает за сложение двух чисел типа [System.Int32](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=netframework-4.7.2)? 
Правильно: инструкция `add`!

---

Перепишем код:

```
double a = 2;
double b = 3;
double c = a + b;
```

Теперь `IL` будет таковым:

```
ldc.r8 2
stloc a
ldc.r8 3
stloc b
ldloc a
ldloc b
add         
stloc c
```

Что изменилось? Только инструкция ***l***oa**dc**onstant, инструкция же сложения так и осталось на своем законном месте)

---

Я не буду продолжать, Вы уже поняли, к чему я клоню)

На уровне `IL` **одна и та же** инструкция `add` спокойненько обрабатывает сложение экземпляров типов `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double`)
А ведь это именно то, что нам нужно!

(К слову, это верно и для инструкций `sub`, `mul`, `div`, `rem`. Подробный лист инструкций `IL` с описанием [найдете здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions))

---

Итак, если Вы можете безболезненно добавить к проекту `.il` файл (к примеру, с помощью расширения [ILSupport](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ins0mniaque.ILSupport) + я также нахожусь в процессе ленивого написания подобного расширения), то метод того же сложения мы можем описать так:

```
.method private static !!T _Add<T>(!!T, !!T) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    ldarg.0     // Кладем на стек нулевой аргумент
    ldarg.1     // Кладем на стек первый аргумент
    add         // Складываем их
    ret         // Возвращаем результат
}
```

В основном файле опишем нечто такое:

```
// Доступные для обработки типы
private static HashSet<Type> AvailableTypes { get; } = new HashSet<Type> {
    typeof(sbyte), typeof(byte),
    typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
    typeof(int), typeof(uint),
    typeof(long), typeof(ulong),
    typeof(float), typeof(double)
};

// Метод сокроем от глаз посторонних,
// так как сюда можно засунуть абсолютно что угодно,
// а мы сего не хотим
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef)]
private static extern T _Add<T>(T A, T B);

// Обертка над нашим методом, которая проверяет,
// допустим ли тип переданных объектов
// На деле можно проверку и в основном методе реализовать,
// но так нагляднее)
public static T Add<T>(T A, T B) where T : struct
{
    if (!AvailableTypes.Contains(typeof(T)))
        throw new TypeAccessException("Unsupported type!");
    return _Add(A, B);
}
```

---

Время тестировать!)

```
sbyte @sbyte = Add((sbyte)122, (sbyte)5); // 127
byte @byte = Add((byte)127, (byte)128); // 255
short @short = Add((short)16384, (short)16383); // 32767
ushort @ushort = Add((ushort)32767, (ushort)32768); // 65535
int @int = Add(1073741823, 1073741824); // 2147483647
uint @uint = Add(2147483647u, 2147483648u); // 4294967295
long @long = Add(4611686018427387903L, 4611686018427387904L); // 9223372036854775807
ulong @ulong = Add(9223372036854775807ul, 9223372036854775808ul); // 18446744073709551615
float @float = Add((float)Math.PI, 2f); // 5.141593
double @double = Add(Math.PI, 2); // 5.1415926535897931
```

Как видите, все прекрасно работает! Один `generic`-метод принимает на вход любой числовой тип и возвращает корректный ответ!

---

Если же Вы в силу каких-то обстоятельств ограничены только `C#`-кодом, то могу предложить Вам решение с помощью [MethodBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Тогда убираем метод `_Add`, а на его месте ставим такую конструкцию:

```
private static MethodInfo _Add
{
    get
    {
        if (__add == null)
        {
            // Создаем билдеры нужных нам объектов
            AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName("asm");
            AssemblyBuilder asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(asmName.Name, $"{asmName.Name}.dll");
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("tp", TypeAttributes.Public);

            // Начинаем строить метод
            MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("_Add", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);

            // Добавляем generic-параметр
            GenericTypeParameterBuilder T = methodBuilder.DefineGenericParameters("T")[0];

            // Указываем, что у нас 2 входных аргумента имеют generic-тип, 
            // а также и выходное значение
            methodBuilder.SetParameters(T, T);
            methodBuilder.SetReturnType(T);

            // Генерируем IL, аналогичный примеру выше
            ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            // Задаем значение локальному полю
            __add = typeBuilder.CreateType().GetMethod("_Add", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        }
        return __add;
    }
}
private static MethodInfo __add;
```

И чуток подправим метод-обертку:

```
public static T Add<T>(T A, T B) where T : struct
{
    if (!AvailableTypes.Contains(typeof(T)))
        throw new TypeAccessException("Unsupported type!");
    return (T)_Add.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)).Invoke(null, new object[] { A, B });
}
```

Весь остальной код остался тем же и ничуть не потерял в работоспособности

Разница лишь в том, что в нулевом случае мы получили нужный метод на этапе компиляции, а здесь - во время выполнения программы)

---

Надеюсь, мое решение показалось Вам хоть немножечко, но интересным, а также привнесло какие-то новые идеи для реализации в строй Ваших мыслей!)

Comment: Вы извращенец, но извращенец любознательный :D интересно вышло)

Comment: @M.Green: а то) Покорно благодарен! P.S. - это у меня ещё руки не дошли до публикации ответа с инструкцией по изменению длины массива без его пересоздания)

Comment: А с помощью `Expression` такое не сделать?

Comment: Пример: https://ideone.com/qkayM2

Comment: @АндрейNOP: а хороший вариант! Чуть позже добавлю в ответ)

Comment: Ну, в общем-то, по ссылке из комментария к этому вопросу есть такое же решение. По хорошему, надо закрыть этот вопрос как дубликат к тому. Или нет... вопросы немного разные, но ответы к ним одинаковые. Надо писать один большой вопрос-ответ и оба этих закрывать на него...

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Ваша правда)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: [готово](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/899928/248572) хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, круто, большая работа, завтра почитаю обязательно :)

Answer (score 0):

Если в методе (в т.ч. конструкторе) принимается аргументы double, можно свободно передавать туда int: действует автоматическое приведение типов.

Чтобы передавать любые объекты, уже придётся использовать Generic.