# Шаблонная функция C#

Tags: c#, c++, generics, шаблоны-с++

Требуется реализовать шаблонную функцию сложения на C#

Нужно разливать эту функцию из C++ на C#

```
template<typename T>
T sum(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Вот эта запись выдает ошибку что операция сложения не перегружена над типом Т

```
public static T sum<T>(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: Например, так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662289/10105

Answer (score 7):

```
public static T sum<T>(T a, T b)
{
    dynamic da = a, db = b;
    return da + db;
}

Console.WriteLine(sum(10, 20)); //30
```

Comment: не нравится? используйте решение от Марка Шевченко. Честно говоря не понимаю я этого: сделать на языке А, точно также как на языке Б. это разные языки, просто пишите так как надо писать на C#. Извиняюсь за эмоции, но сильно разозлил минус )

Comment: Кстати говоря он предлагает тоже самое. А у меня короче.

Comment: Ну тут еще не ясно кто минус поставил и за что. Я бы не сильно на это злился, найдется добрый человек, который приложит подорожник в виде плюсика... уже нашелся.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов не сочтите за придирку, но тут есть проблемы с безопасностью типов. Например в этом случае код скомпилируется, но выкинет исключение в рантайме: `sum(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);`

Comment: Ха, если так из-за каждого минуса злиться, то никаких нервов может не хватить. Я вам больше скажу, что даже под топовыми ответами частенько бывают минусы, и это не означает, что ответ неправильный. Просто кому-то он не понравился. Возможно, в вашем ответе не хватает пояснений _почему_ этот runtime вариант будет работать, и по какой причине в C# невозможно выполнить данную задачу в compile-time без приведений типов. В любом случае, если ответ хороший, то плюсы перевесят (по крайней мере на enSO так).

Comment: Error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create' (CS0656) (Types) - в чес проблема просто перенс код

Comment: @АлексейОбухов не могли бы привести пример как правильно реализовать такое на C# то есть функцию которая складывает любые типы, которые можно сложить

Comment: @Nikita скорее не понравился не ответ, а участник который его дал...

Comment: @shotInLeg явно подключите Microsoft.CSharp в references чтобы заработал dynamic

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению такого же элегантного способа в C# нет, так как в этом языке для обобщений не предусмотрены ограничения по наличию оператора. В качестве несколько неуклюжей альтернативы можно предложить разве что написание обобщённых методов, заменяющих операторы, таких, как `Add`, `Multiple` и тд

Comment: Как можно это реализовать?