# Сделать Generic метод

Tags: c#

Есть обобщенный класс:

```
public struct Range<T>
{
    public T From { get; set; }
    public T To { get; set; }

    public bool HasValue(T value)
    {
        // Нужно написать проверку входа в диапазон
    }
}
```

`T` - может быть только числом (`int`, `double`) или датой (`DateTime`) и может быть `Nullable`.

Нужно реализовать метод `HasValue`, который будет проверять входит ли `value` в диапазон от `From` до `To`.

Возможно ли такое без использования приведений и перегрузок?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://ideone.com/WBbU8d

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public struct Range<T>
{
    public T From { get; set; }
    public T To { get; set; }

    public bool HasValue(T value)
    {
        return value != null
            && (From == null || Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(From, value) <= 0)
            && (To == null || Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(To, value) >= 0);
    }
}
```

И проверка:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Range <int> { From = 10, To = 16 };
        Console.WriteLine("var a = new Range <int> { From = 10, To = 16 };");
        Console.WriteLine(a.HasValue(0));
        Console.WriteLine(a.HasValue(15));
        Console.WriteLine(a.HasValue(17));
        Console.WriteLine();

        var b = new Range <int?> { From = 10, To = 16 };
        Console.WriteLine("var b = new Range <int?> { From = 10, To = 16 };");
        Console.WriteLine(b.HasValue(null));
        Console.WriteLine(b.HasValue(0));
        Console.WriteLine(b.HasValue(15));
        Console.WriteLine(b.HasValue(17));
        Console.WriteLine();

        var c = new Range <int?> { From = null, To = 16 };
        Console.WriteLine("var c = new Range <int?> { From = null, To = 16 };");
        Console.WriteLine(c.HasValue(null));
        Console.WriteLine(c.HasValue(0));
        Console.WriteLine(c.HasValue(15));
        Console.WriteLine(c.HasValue(17));
        Console.WriteLine();

        var d = new Range <int?> { From = 10, To = null };
        Console.WriteLine("var d = new Range <int?> { From = 10, To = null };");
        Console.WriteLine(d.HasValue(null));
        Console.WriteLine(d.HasValue(0));
        Console.WriteLine(d.HasValue(15));
        Console.WriteLine(d.HasValue(17));
        Console.WriteLine();

        var e = new Range <int?> { From = null, To = null };
        Console.WriteLine("var e = new Range <int?> { From = null, To = null };");
        Console.WriteLine(e.HasValue(null));
        Console.WriteLine(e.HasValue(0));
        Console.WriteLine(e.HasValue(15));
        Console.WriteLine(e.HasValue(17));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему `value != null`? Отрезок `[null, null]` по идее должен содержать `null`.

Comment: @VladD, интересная версия. Просто мне null там всю картину портил. Можно сделать `(value != null || From == null && To == null)`, но непонятно, насколько такая логика нужна.

Answer (score 8):

За сравнение отвечает интерфейс `IComparable`, можете ограничить типы им. Правда тогда Вы не сможете передавать в качестве T типы Nullable. Можно будет только сравнивать их с From и To через перегрузку `HasValue(T? value)`. Лучшего решения мне в голову не приходит.

```
public struct Range<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public T From
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public T To
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool HasValue(T value)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(From) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(To) <= 0;
    }

    public bool HasValue(T? value)
    {
        return value.HasValue && value.Value.CompareTo(From) >= 0 && value.Value.CompareTo(To) <= 0;
    }
}
```

---

**UPD Класс с Nullable проверкой (не проверялся, работоспособность не гарантирую)**

```
public struct Range<T> 
{
    public T From
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public T To
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool HasValue(T value) 
    {
        IComparable _from = null;
        IComparable _to = null;
        IComparable _value = null;

        if (From != null) 
        {
            _from = GetValue(From) as IComparable;
        }
        if (To != null)
        {
            _to = GetValue(To) as IComparable;
        }
        if (value != null)
        {
            _value = GetValue(value) as IComparable;
        }

        if (_value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        bool checkFrom = false;
        if (_from == null || _from != null && _value.CompareTo(_from) >= 0) checkFrom = true;

        bool checkTo = false;
        if (_to == null || _to != null && _value.CompareTo(_to) <= 0) checkTo = true;

        return checkFrom && checkTo;
    }

    private T GetValue<T>(T t) { return t; }
    private T GetValue<T>(T? t) where T : struct { return t.Value; }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(new Range<int>() { From = -20, To = 20 }.HasValue(10)); //true
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<int>() { From = -20, To = 20 }.HasValue(-100)); //false
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<int>() { From = -20, To = 20 }.HasValue(100)); //false

        Console.WriteLine(new Range<int?>() { From = -20, To = 20 }.HasValue(10)); //true
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<int?>() { From = -20, To = 20 }.HasValue(-100)); //false
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<int?>() { From = -20, To = 20 }.HasValue(100)); //false
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<int?>() { From = null, To = 20 }.HasValue(10)); //true
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<int?>() { From = -20, To = null }.HasValue(10)); //true
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<int?>() { From = -20, To = null }.HasValue(-100)); //false

        Console.WriteLine(new Range<DateTime>() { From = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), To = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) }.HasValue(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2))); //true
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<DateTime>() { From = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), To = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) }.HasValue(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10))); //false
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<DateTime>() { From = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), To = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) }.HasValue(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10))); //false
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<DateTime?>() { From = null, To = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) }.HasValue(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2))); //true
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<DateTime?>() { From = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), To = null }.HasValue(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2))); //true
        Console.WriteLine(new Range<DateTime?>() { From = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), To = null }.HasValue(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100))); //false

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `IComparable` не может быть `Nullable`, поэтому не получится сделать так: `var range = new Range<int?>();`

Comment: А если добавить перегрузку `public bool HasValue(T? value)`? Потому что делать nullable края несколько странновато.

Comment: @Qwertiy если ограничить через `IComparable`, то не даст сделать `T?`. А если ограничить классом, не даст сравнить значения. Nullable края нужны когда отсутствует одна из границ диапазона, от 0 до бесконечности.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, дополнил ответ с учетом замечания. Skrim, более полного решения мне на ум не приходит, если не использовать приведения, перегрузки и т.д.

Comment: @Skrim, CompaкуЕщ c null'ом так себе работает обычно.

Comment: Можно проверить `T` на `Nullable`, т запускать проверку либо через `x.CompareTo(y)`, либо `x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value)` в зависимости от результата проверки.

Comment: @AlexKrass в вашем примере параметр `T?` не работает, нужно добавить еще ограничение `struct`. И еще `From` и `To` тоже могут быть `null`, можно к ним тоже добавить `?`. Но просто дописать `?` кажется не подходящим, хотелось бы иметь возможность управлять этим при создании переменной `var r = new Range<int?>();`, однако в этом случае нужно убирать все ограничения что приводит к не возможности сравнивать. Видимо без использования отдельных не обобщенных классов не обойтись, либо как написал @VladD  инстанциировать нужный класс внутри generic :(

Comment: @Skrim, я обновил ответ с новым классом, попробовал по быстрому набросать исходя из советов VladD с проверкой. Посмотрите, может он Вам подойдет. Хотя я не уверен, будет ли он нормально работать.

Comment: `IComparer` не поможет?

Comment: Запостил ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну с `IComparer` я еще ни разу не встречался и не подозревал о его существовании, буду знать. Спасибо за ответ, коротко и просто.

Answer (score 6):

Для таких типов обычно создают кучу перегрузок. Можно посмотреть, например, метод `Console.WriteLine`. Можно поступить так же: создать множество структур/классов для работы с конкретным типом. Чтобы не писать все их вручную можно применить кодогенерацию T4.

В файле `tt` пишем:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

using System;

namespace TestApp
{
    <# 
    var types = new string[] { "SByte", "Byte", "Char", "Int16", "UInt16", "Int32", "UInt32",
        "Int64", "UInt64", "Single", "Double", "Decimal", "DateTime", "DateTimeOffset" };

    foreach(var T in types) {
    #>
    public struct Range<#=T#>
    {
        public <#=T#> From { get; set; }
        public <#=T#> To { get; set; }

        public bool HasValue(<#=T#> value)
        {
            return value >= From && value <= To;
        }
    }
    public struct RangeNullable<#=T#>
    {
        public <#=T#>? From { get; set; }
        public <#=T#>? To { get; set; }

        public bool HasValue(<#=T#>? value)
        {
            return value >= From && value <= To;
        }
    }
    <#
        }
    #>
}
```

Типы добавить/убавить по желанию.
После компиляции будет сгенерирован файл `cs` со множеством структур.

Далее нужно будет создавать и использовать экземпляры структур явно указанных типов:

```
var range = new RangeInt32();
var range2 = new RangeNullableDateTime();
```

В первоначальном варианте это было бы:

```
var range = new Range<int>();
var range2 = new Range<DateTime?>();
```

Comment: Можно ещё сгенерировать один общий generic-тип, который будет внутри себя проверять generic-параметр и инстанциировать внутри себя нужный конкретный класс. Наподобие этого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662289/10105

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, А что за файл `tt`?

Comment: @Lightness - [Text Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb126445.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Ещё один вариант реализации.

Условия: либо тип `T` не `Nullable`, и реализует `IComparable<Т>`, либо он есть тип `T1?`, и уж `T1` реализует `IComparable<Т1>`. К сожалению, не проверяется в compile time.

```
class Range<T>
{
    // компаратор для не-nullable-случая
    static int CompareNonNullable<V>(V l, V r) where V : IComparable<V> => l.CompareTo(r);

    // компаратор для nullable-случая
    static int CompareNullable<V>(V? l, V? r) where V : struct, IComparable<V>
    {
        if (l == null)
            return r == null ? 0 : 1;
        else if (r == null)
            return -1;
        else return l.Value.CompareTo(r.Value);
    }

    static Range()
    {
        Type parameter = typeof(T);
        Type nullableBase = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));

        Type underlying = nullableBase ?? parameter; // T или T1

        // проверка на IComparable
        var icomparable = typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(underlying);
        var hasInterface = underlying.GetInterfaces().Contains(icomparable);
        if (!hasInterface)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Type should implement IComparable generic interface");

        var methodName = (nullableBase == null) ? nameof(CompareNonNullable) :
                                                  nameof(CompareNullable);
        var rawMI = typeof(Range<T>).GetMethod(
                        methodName,
                        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var genericMI = rawMI.MakeGenericMethod(underlying);

        comparer = (Func<T, T, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                                        typeof(Func<T, T, int>), genericMI);
    }

    static Func<T, T, int> comparer;

    public Range(T from, T to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public bool Contains(T t) => comparer(From, t) <= 0 && comparer(t, To) <= 0;

    public T From { get; }
    public T To { get; }
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```
var intRange = new Range<int>(0, 5);
Console.WriteLine(intRange.Contains(5));

var dtRange = new Range<DateTime?>(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), null);
Console.WriteLine(dtRange.Contains(DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: Ой.. А не сложновато? Я вроде проще написал?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, я не использую `Comparer<T>.Default`, a `IComparable<T>`, так что они немного разные. Но да, с `Comparer.Default` выглядит как-то попроще.

Comment: Но Comparer.Default ведь умеет IComparable?

Comment: @Qwertiy: [Это да](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs,52). Но он умеет сравнивать что угодно, это на мой вкус оверкилл.

Comment: Хотя нет, не что угодно. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/comparer.cs,85

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через extension:

```
public static class RangeExtensions
{
    public static bool HasValue<T>(this Range<T> range, T value, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
        where T : struct
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        return comparer.Compare(value, range.From) >= 0 && comparer.Compare(value, range.To) <= 0;
    }

    public static bool HasValue<T>(this Range<T?> range, T? value, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
        where T : struct
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        if (value == null || range.From == null || range.To == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return comparer.Compare(value.Value, range.From.Value) >= 0 && comparer.Compare(value.Value, range.To.Value) <= 0;
    }
}
```

Потенциально проблема с производительностью этого метода если Range структура - структура будет передаваться по значению. Если Range будет классом или операция не частая, то вот так попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Реализация примерно такая:

```
public bool HasValue(T value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return false;
    return (value >= From) && (To >= value);
}
```

PS. В первый раз написал вообще не верно. 
Получается, что ничего приводить не надо, т.к. числа и `DataTime` мы можем сравнивать. И первым делом надо проверить на `null`, а потом сравнить обычным способом.

Comment: Мы не можем сравнивать переменные обобщенного типа напрямую.