# Как в обобщенном классе (generic) задать ограничение "только float или int" для типа?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Есть класс `Parameter`:

```
public abstract class Parameter<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }
    //...
}
```

Как в таком классе для типа `T` задать ограничение только на определенные *базовые* типы? Хотелось бы иметь что-то наподобие этого:

```
public abstract class Parameter<T> where T : int, float, double, string
{
    public T Value { get; }
    //...
}
```

IntelliSense сразу ругается на каждый тип:

> "int" не является допустимым ограничением. Тип, использованный в
>   качестве ограничения, должен быть интерфейсом, незапечатанным классом
>   или параметром-типом.

**UPD.** Или просто оставить тип без ограничений и ничего страшного в этом нет, что можно случайно создать класс с не таким типом, который ожидалось видеть?

**UPD 2.** Отвечаю на вопрос `для какой цели нужно ограничение типа`. Есть некоторая абстракция `Параметр`, которая инкапсулирует в себе данные определенного базового типа. У него есть поля `Значение`, `Имя` и `Максимальное и минимальное значение`. Читая ответы на вопросы, я понял, что нет смысла ограничивать данный тип параметра.

Comment: Если вам нужно производить _вычисления_ с разными _числовыми_ типами, то смотрите эти темы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562575/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662148/184217). А если производить какие-либо другие операции, наподобие сравнения, с разными типами, то смотрите [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/686430/184217).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько причин, по которым этот код не может работать в C#

```
where T : int, float, double, string
```

Когда вы указываете ограничение `T : Type` то это значит, что `T` может быть как типа `Type` так и потомком типа `Type`. Следовательно, конструкция `where T : int, float` семантически означает следующее — тип `T` должен наследовать от типов `int` и `float`. Это не сработает по двум причинам:

1. В C# запрещено множественное наследование
2. Конструкция `T : int` не может работать, так как `int` это структура, а структуры не поддерживают наследование. Это свойство классов. Можете проверить это на примере: `Generic<T, U> where T : struct where U : T`. (замените `struct` на `class` и все заработает)

Зато компилятор предлагает вам рабочие варианты:

> Тип, использованный в качестве ограничения, должен быть *интерфейсом*,
>   [незапечатанным](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) классом или параметром-типом.

Cтруктуры и классы могут имплементировать интерфейсы, поэтому ограничение типа на интерфейс может иметь смысл как для структур, так и для классов, например в ограничение `T : IComparable` можно подставить как `int` так и `string` так как оба этих типа имплементируют этот интерфейс.

> Или просто оставить тип без ограничений и ничего страшного в этом нет,
>   что можно случайно создать класс с не таким типом, который ожидалось
>   видеть

Для этого следует ответить на вопрос, для чего вы задаете ограничение типа? Вы видите что-то общее между типами `int` и `string`? Вы хотите обращаться к общим членам этих типов или использовать их как-то иначе в полиморфном контексте? Если нет, то, наверное, и нет смысла искусственно ограничивать тип-параметр.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Можете взглянуть на обновленный вопрос, если вас интересует, зачем нужно было ограничение типа.

Comment: Для таких целей вам, наверное, лучше сконструировать свой собственный тип, как в примере @Gordory. Ну и подумать, как максимальное и минимальное значение должно работать в контексте строк?

Comment: тип `string` я привел исключительно для примера) как правило, это будут целые числа и с плавающей точкой.

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, никак.

Можно использовать только constraints указанные в документации:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

В качестве обходного пути можно создать класс-обёртку для нужных типов:

```
public class WrappedInt
{
    public int Value { get; }

    public WrappedInt(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class Foo<T> where T : WrappedInt, WrappedFloat, ...
{
    public Foo(T ariphmeticValue)
    {
    }
}
```

**UPD.** Касаемо последнего вопроса: сильно зависит от задачи. Если использование других типов будут вызывать unhandled exceptions - это плохо.

Comment: Обертка хорошо подходит для данной задачи, спасибо!