# Как заполнить матрицу универсального типа при заполнении рандомом

Tags: c#, generics

Я пытаюсь написать заполнение матрицы универсального типа для конкретного типа int. Но мне пишет что Random не может работать с универсальным типом. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, и если да то как решили? В данном коде я хочу обработать заполнение для матрицы типа `int` В коде это функция `public void fillMatrixByRandom(int max_value)`

```
    class Matrix<T> where T : struct
    {
        T[,] matrix_first;
        T[,] matrix_second;

        public Matrix(int strings_matrix_first, int columns_matrix_first, int strings_matrix_second, int columns_matrix_second)
        {
            matrix_first = new T[columns_matrix_first, strings_matrix_first];
            matrix_second = new T[columns_matrix_second, strings_matrix_second];
        }

        public void fillMatrixByRandom(int max_value)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            if(matrix_first is int)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix_first.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix_first.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        matrix_first[i, j] = rand.Next(max_value);
                    }
                }
            }
        
       
        }
        public void showMatrix()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix_first.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix_first.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(matrix_first[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix_second.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix_second.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(matrix_second[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        ~Matrix()
        {
            matrix_first = null;
            matrix_second = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Какой тип элементов в массиве `matrix_first`? Какой тип возвращает `Random.Next`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP массив планируется с int, а random.next возвращает int. Конкретно в данной ситуации мы можем обработать это? или нет.

Comment: `matrix_first is int` — это всегда false, потому что никакой массив не является `int`, надо проверять как-то типа `typeof(T) == typeof(int)`

Comment: Ну и все равно это не сработает, потому что слева `T`, а справа `int`

Comment: В самом фреймворке в этих случаях используется множество перегрузок с примитивными типами. Можно их сгенерировать. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/686451/184217

Comment: Зацените: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562580/184217

Comment: `matrix_first[i, j] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(rand.Next(max_value), typeof(T));`

Comment: Ссылки были полезны? Мой предыдущий комментарий помог?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, они мне помогли не меньше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class Matrix - темплейт/generic. насколько я помню, чтобы темплейты заработали, надо:

1. объявить темплейт. это сделано, но функция fillMatrixByRandom не должна быть определена в нём. класса на данный момент ещё нет, а функция пытается записать туда инты.
2. обявить объект этого типа, специфицировав T, например `Matrix<int>`. компиль поймёт это и сделает сделает реальный класс с интами. см [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)
3. передать объект класса в функцию или расширение fillMatrixByRandom, которая принимает в себя Matrix и заполняет его интами.

GC.Collect(); на мой взгляд излишен. т.к. GC выполняется сам и дёргать его без особой надобности не надо. при частом вызове GC можно получить негативный эффект в плане производительности.

Comment: Я бы тут вообще не использовал деструктор т.к. в шарпах есть пресловутый gc , но преподователь требует чтобы был деструктор, ну а делать пустой деструктор не вижу смысла, но за замечание спасибо, буду знать на будущее

Comment: Эт всё хорошо... Но какое отношение это имеет к вопросу?