# Использование обобщенных методов типа generics в c#

Tags: c#, generics

прошу помочь разобраться в использовании обобщенных методов. Проблема в следующем: я проверяю введенное значение, чтобы оно было больше нуля, пытаюсь это сделать следующим методом:

```
public static void CheckGreaterZero<T> (ref T parametr)
        {
            try
            {
                if (parametr < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception
                        ("Данное значение не может быть отрицательным!\n" +
                               "Программа будет завершена.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: " + e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

но получается ошибка "Оператор < нельзя применить к операнду типа T и int". Для меня важен универсальный параметр, т.к. данным методом я буду проверять значения int и double, можно ли как-то поправить данную ошибку и корректно написать данный метод?
Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: неа, пока проще использовать перегрузки вместо generics

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Объединение методов для int, long, double, BigInteger в один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793478/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-int-long-double-biginteger-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd)

Comment: можно вместо сравнения с нулем воспользоваться сравнением с `default(T)`, по-идее должно сработать.

Comment: @Bulson, там же операция меньше, default(T) тут не поможет. Но можно какой-нибудь IComparable<T> ограничение поставить

Comment: @Grundy а ну, да...

Comment: Я пробовал использовать Comparable<T> , но тогда метод не работает или я делаю что-то неверно. Пробовал писать так - public static void CheckGreaterZero<T>(ref T parametr)
            where T : System.IComparable<T>
        {
            try
            {
                if (parametr.CompareTo() < 0), но что нужно поставить в скобки к CompareTo(), если ставлю parametr.CompareTo(parametr), то метод не работает.

Comment: в метод нужно передавать то, с чем должно произойти сравнение, в данном случае `0`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так сделай

```
 class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var g = 7.6;
                CheckGreaterZero(ref g);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }

            public static void CheckGreaterZero<T>(ref T parametr)
            {
                if (typeof(T) == Type.GetType("System.Double"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("System.Double");
                }
                if (typeof(T) == Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("System.Int32");
                }
            }

        }
```