# Синтаксис обобщённого метода, возвращающего массив

Tags: c#

Необходимо написать обобщенный метод, который принимает массив из цифр (int, long etc.), прибавляет к каждому элементу некую константу того же типа, и возвращает уже новый массив. Я попытался реализовать это следующим образом:

```
static public T[] SomeMethod<T>(T[] myArray, T myConst)
    {
        T[myArray.Length] resultArray = default(T);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < myArray.Length; counter++)
        {
            resultArray[counter] = myArray[counter] + myConst;
        }
        return resultArray;
    }
```

Во-первых, судя по Шиелду 4.0, синтаксис подобного обобщённого метода выглядит следующим образом: возвращаемый_тип имя_метода<список_параметров_типа>(список_параметров) {...}. Тут сразу возникает вопрос - обязательно ли указывать список параметров в угловых скобках после имени метода? Реализовывая другие методы ранее я этого не делал, и все отлично работало. Получается это не обязательно? Во-вторых, объявляя в этом методе локальную переменную нового массива resultArray,  мне выдается ошибка со следующим пояснением: " 'T' является тип, который недопустим в данном контексте". Но почему? Ведь на месте всех <> будет тип который я передал в качестве параметра, в том числе там где я создаю новый результирующий массив. Почему возникает данная ошибка? Так же я пытался хотя бы частично решить данную задачу , не создавая новый массив, а возвращая модифицированную версию принятого:

```
static public T[] SomeMethod<T>(T[] myArray, T myConst)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < myArray.Length; counter++)
        {
            myArray[counter] = myArray[counter] + myConst;
        }
        return myArray;
    }
```

Однако в таком случае, в строке  myArray[counter] = myArray[counter] + myConst; возникает ошибка "оператор '+' невозможно применить к операнду типа 'T' и 'T'". Данную ошибку я так же не понимаю. Что я делаю не так, и как решить поставленную задачу?

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662148/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562575/184217).

Comment: myArray[counter] + myConst<< в вашем коде T - может не уметь работать оператором +. У самого возникал подобный вопрос, есть, правда, реализация через рефлексию (попытка вызвать оператор + для двух экземпляров вашего T), но, 10 раз подумайте над другими реализациями.

Comment: Для примера, могу вам порекомендовать передать в ваш метод лямбду, в которой вы сможете сделать что хотите, но, не уверен что это тоже является оптимальным путём.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я сам придумал эту задачу, и наивно полагал что решение будет крайне простым, а при реализации оказалось множество подводных камней. Как вообще можно решить поставленную задачу? Можете показать? Я пока что еще не очень хорошо умею в рефлексию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ: использовать `dynamic`. Однако, это работает медленно и может упасть в рантайме.

```
static public T[] SomeMethod<T>(T[] myArray, T myConst)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < myArray.Length; counter++)
    {
        dynamic item = myArray[counter];
        item += myConst;
        myArray[counter] = item;
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вам, всё же, необходимо вынести логику за цикл, могу предложить пару вариантов:

1. Вынесение логики через лямбды:

   ```
   private delegate T Callback<T>(T value);

   private static T[] Do<T>(ref T[] array, Callback<T> callback){
       T[] newArray = new T[array.Length];
       for(int i=array.Length-1; i>=0; i--){
           newArray[i] = callback(array[i]);
       }
       return newArray;
   }

   private static void print<T>(T[] array) {
       foreach (T item in array) {
           Console.Write(item.ToString()+" ");
       }
       Console.Write("\n");
   }

   public static void Main(string[] args) {

       int[]   array1 = new int[]  {1,    2,    3};
       float[] array2 = new float[]{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};

       print(array1);
       print(Do(ref array1,(int value)=>{
           return value+1;
       }));

       print(array2);
       print(Do(ref array2,(float value)=>{
           return value*2;
       }));

       Console.ReadKey();
   }
   ```

Здесь компилятор уже знает типы аргументов, соответственно, проблем с операторами не будет. Вся логика работы с одним элементов выносится в лямбда-функцию.

2. Использование рефлексии (чисто теоретический вариант):

   ```
   private static T[] Sum<T>(ref T[] array, T value){
       T[] newArray = new T[array.Length];
       MethodInfo plusMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod("op_Addition", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
       for(int i=array.Length-1; i>=0; i--){
           newArray[i] = (T)plusMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { array[i], value });
       }
       return newArray;
   }

   private static void print<T>(T[] array) {
       foreach (T item in array) {
           Console.Write(item.ToString()+" ");
       }
       Console.Write("\n");
   }

   public static void Main(string[] args) {

       MyClass[] array = new MyClass[] { new MyClass(1), new MyClass(2), new MyClass(3)};

       print(array);
       print(Sum(ref array, new MyClass(1)));

       Console.ReadKey();
   }
   ```

Проблема этого варианта в том, что примитивные типы не имеют оператора +, эту операцию над примитивными числами выполняет уже не сам шарп. Поэтому, чисто технически, вызов своих классов будет работать аналогично instance += anotherInstance;

Comment: нет необходимости получать метод на каждой итерации цикла

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, исправил)

Comment: буду изучать ответы, но почему не работают мои варианты? не понимаю пояснения компилятора. И так и не понял, обязательно ли указывать список параметров в угловых скобках после имени метода?

Comment: @АлексейФедотов, я вам уже сказал в комментарии под вопросом. Заранее неизвестно что такое T, и есть ли у него оператор +. Вот вам и выдаётся сообщение, что нельзя совершить такую операцию над T переменными. Если бы подобное было предусмотрено, думаю, обошлось бы каким нибудь Do<T>(...) where T : operator+ { ... }, как это сделано, например, с new(), но, к сожалению, такого нет...

Answer (score 2):

Для начала - нет смысла делать отдельный метод для каждой операции. Потому гораздо лучше передать операцию трансформации как параметр.

Начнем с простого примера

```
public T[] Transform<T>(T[] source, Func<T, T> transform)
{
    var result = new T[source.Length];      
    for(var i=0; i<source.Length; i++)
        result[i] = transform(source[i]);           
    return result;
}
```

У этого примера есть 2 очевидных недостатка:

1. Он не статический, а значит будет кушать память
2. Он возвращает коллекцию того же типа всегда

Давайте это испроавим и выполним его как расширяющий метод:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static K[] Transform<T, K>(this T[] source, Func<T, K> transform)
    {
        var result = new K[source.Length];      
        for(var i=0; i<source.Length; i++)
            result[i] = transform(source[i]);           
        return result;
    }
}
```

Это выглядит уже лучше. Его можно использовать вот так:

```
var result = new[] {1, 2, 3}.Transform(x=>x.ToString());
```

Но и у этого метода есть недостатки

1. Он работает только с массивами
2. При каждом вызове он будет выделять новую память

Например, вот это выражение

```
var result = new[] {1, 2, 3}
    .Transform(x=>x.ToString())
    .Transform(int.Parse)
    .Transform(x=>x+10);
```

Выделит память 3 раза, хотя нам по сути надо только один раз. Что можно сделать? Для тго, чтобы расширить круг потребителей, можно запускать метод не только на массивах, но и на всем, что перечисляется. Чтобы минимизировать выделение памяти, можно вообще память не выделять, а использовать ленивую энумерацию. Как это выглядит:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<K> Transform<T, K>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, K> transform)
    {
        foreach(var item in source)
            yield return transform(item);
    }
}
```

Преимущества этого в том, что теперь выражение

```
var result = new[] {1, 2, 3}
    .Transform(x=>x.ToString())
    .Transform(int.Parse)
    .Transform(x=>x+10);
```

вообще не будет ничего вычислять, пока результат не начнут явно перечислять. Примерно по такому механизму и работает функция Linq [Select](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d3e6cf8553f8ad92,references), которую вполне можно использовать и в вашем случае.

то есть по сути, выражение можно переписать вот так

```
var result2 = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .Select(x => x + 10);
```

И это будет то же самое, что мы только что написали, только без использования нашей функции.

Comment: У автора изменяется исходный массив, а linq создает новый. И вопрос все-таки про то, как сделать обобщенный метод для арифметических вычислений.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `Необходимо написать обобщенный метод, который принимает массив из цифр (int, long etc.), прибавляет к каждому элементу некую константу того же типа, и возвращает уже новый массив.` автору надо решить проблему, я хотел показать, что, возможно, способ, которым он решает проблему не самый лучший, потому я написал что написал

Answer (score 2):

Вам точно нужен SomeMethod? Потому что вместо него вы можете воспользоваться Linq в том месте где это вам требуется

```
    var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var myConst = 1;
    var result = array.Select(x => x + myConst).ToArray();
```

Comment: У автора изменяется исходный массив, а linq создает новый. И вопрос все-таки про то, как сделать обобщенный метод для арифметических вычислений.

Comment: Цитата из вопроса "и возвращает уже новый массив". Мне кажется, linq - это именно то, что в итоге хотел получить автор, и это более правильный подход.