# Как написать метод/класс, который бы одинаково работал со всеми числовыми типами?

Tags: c#, generics

Предположим, я хочу описать `generic`-класс, выполняющий роль калькулятора, таким образом, чтобы он одинаково работал для всех числовых типов. Т.е.:

- sbyte
- byte
- short
- ushort
- int
- uint
- long
- ulong
- float
- double

Сложность задачи заключается в том, что пусть все эти типы и объединяет наличие определения для их экземпляров арифметических операций, однако они не наследуют какого-либо общего интерфейса типа `IArithmetical`, `INumber`. А также [ограничение where](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) в `C#` не позволяет нам описать нечто вроде:

```
public static void Add<T>(T A, T B) where T : +, -, *, /, % ...
```

Так что компилятор не может быть уверен в том, что для всех возможных типов, эксплуатирующих метод, определены нужные операции

Это приводит к тому, что подобный код:

```
public class Calculator<T>
{
    public T Add(T A, T B) => A + B;
    public T Sub(T A, T B) => A - B;
    public T Mul(T A, T B) => A * B;
    public T Div(T A, T B) => A / B;
    public T Mod(T A, T B) => A % B;
}
```

Увы, но просто невозможно скомпилировать: по описанным выше причинам будет выкинута [ошибка CS0019](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0019)

---

Так что же делать в данной ситуации? Возможно-ли вообще средствами `C#` описать `generic`-класс/метод, который бы мог работать с числами и только с ними?

Comment: Вот ещё в копилку: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Genumerics/

Comment: @VladD, прошло 3 года, но никогда не поздно :)

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1309237/10105) пример использования, и автор заявляет, что производительность очень хорошая.

Comment: Вот бенчмарки: https://github.com/TylerBrinkley/Genumerics#performance-comparison

Comment: И в это с лёгкостью верится, ибо вызов метода по типу `public static T Add<T>(T a, T b) { return typeof(T) == typeof(int) ? (T)(object)((int)(object)a + (int)(object)(b)) : throw new Exception(); }` с int будет заменён JIT непосредственно на операцию сложения. JIT больно умный стал за эти годы :)

Comment: Ага, и правда, они там научились делать девиртуализацию, и это круто!

Comment: Чтобы не оставаться голословным: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACAZQAtsoAHAGW2ADoASgFcAdhgCW+GAG4axAMwMyS8gHYaAbxoMdDANoApcRgDiMETCjiwACgwBPDjAgAzG+LEBKTwF1tuw2MzCytbBydXGyEPDG8/al19I1NzS2s7R2c3ABMIIWAAGxg4/x0FFSQGABUGAEFs7OC0sAAeKoA+GxrsNGqGYE9Shi0ExN1idVGxsfCsrs8GAF5FhlnImIWAfiHp6fmbCGAAKxgwWJt3LwPj09jsBgBqBkvzw5OzzxsBhZAd3bW3FUFstVplItEvAxtlNdnsgdd3ucohsEbdPPcnsirm80V9vAxfjDYQD5ksViTcvkils/rCdPscR8LpTCsVUR8Mc8WdT2edvgTaTMWFAIAB3BgWcUAUQQYBgHAkEBENk8shhAF8aOqgA===

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Обновлено:** Начиная с .NET 6, теперь [нативно поддерживается](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/) работа с обобщенными вычислениями (Generic Math).

---

Я начал этот топик, дабы рассмотреть все известные (мне) способы решения поставленной проблемы и дать максимально развернутый ответ на сей довольно таки частый вопрос

Если вдруг Вам известен метод, который я по каким-то причинам не описал в данном посте - напишите, пожалуйста, об этом в комментариях!

Итак, поехали!

---

## #0.0: Дублирование кода и никаких generic'ов

Бесспорно, самым банальным решением, к которому и прибегают все отчаявшиеся, является простое дублирование кода для каждого из типов:

```
public sbyte Add(sbyte A, sbyte B) => (sbyte)(A + B);
public byte Add(byte A, byte B) => (byte)(A + B);
public short Add(short A, short B) => (short)(A + B);
public ushort Add(ushort A, ushort B) => (ushort)(A + B);
public int Add(int A, int B) => A + B;
public uint Add(uint A, uint B) => A + B;
public long Add(long A, long B) => A + B;
public ulong Add(ulong A, ulong B) => A + B;
public float Add(float A, float B) => A + B;
public double Add(double A, double B) => A + B;
```

###Плюсы:

- По крайней мере это работает)
- Доступны операции только для заданных типов
- Операции для типов определены во время компиляции (не придется жертвовать временем и прочими ресурсами во время исполнения для создания данных методов)

###Минусы:

- Очевидно, что это куча <s>хлама</s> дублирующего кода, которая ломает всякое изящество проекта
- Если вдруг метод `Add` немного поменяет свою логику (как бы странно это ни звучало), то переписывать придется каждый из *N* методов!

---

## #0.1: Кодогенерация

Чтобы хоть как-то упростить себе жизнь и не писать множество однотипных методов, можно прибегнуть к кодогенерации с помощью встроенного в `Visual Studio` [T4-генератора](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb126445.aspx):

Добавим в проект файл `Calc.tt` по шаблону `Text Template` (`Текстовый шаблон`). Запишем в него следующий код:

```
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>

namespace Calc
{
    public class Calculator
    {
    <# 
        // Типы, используемые в методах
        string[] usingTypes = new[] { "sbyte", "byte", "short", "ushort", "int", "uint", "long", "ulong", "float", "double" };

        // Экземпляры некоторых типов перед операцией кастятся к int, так что результат нужно привести обратно
        HashSet<string> needCast= new HashSet<string> { "sbyte", "byte", "short", "ushort" };

        foreach(string T in usingTypes)
        {
    #>
        public <#=T#> Add(<#=T#> A, <#=T#> B) => <#=(needCast.Contains(T) ? $"({T})(A + B)" : "A + B")#>;
    <#
        }
    #>
    }
}
```

Выхлоп (`Calc.cs`) будет выглядеть так:

```
namespace Calc
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public sbyte Add(sbyte A, sbyte B) => (sbyte)(A + B);
        public byte Add(byte A, byte B) => (byte)(A + B);
        public short Add(short A, short B) => (short)(A + B);
        public ushort Add(ushort A, ushort B) => (ushort)(A + B);
        public int Add(int A, int B) => A + B;
        public uint Add(uint A, uint B) => A + B;
        public long Add(long A, long B) => A + B;
        public ulong Add(ulong A, ulong B) => A + B;
        public float Add(float A, float B) => A + B;
        public double Add(double A, double B) => A + B;
    }
}
```

###Плюсы:

- См. пункт **0.0**)
- Мы избавились от проблемной модификации логики метода: теперь вся логика сосредоточена в одном месте, так что достаточно отредактировать алгоритм всего один раз, а кодогенератор проделает всю грязную работу за Вас)

###Минусы:

- Поддержка подсветки синтаксиса текстовых шаблонов в `Visual Studio` хромает, мягко говоря. Так что о комфортном коддинге можно забыть)
- Это до сих пор нежелательное и лишь слегка прикрытое дублирование кода

<sub>Данный подход был первоначально описан в [ответе от Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662346/248572)</sub>

---

## #1.0: dynamic

Так как мы решаем проблему, которая неведома языкам с динамической типизацией, то следующим очевидным решением будет использование [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic):

> Тип `dynamic` включает операции, в которых он применяется для обхода проверки типов во время компиляции. Такие операции разрешаются во время выполнения.

Собственно, нам это подходит!

Перепишем метод `Add` таким образом:

```
// Достаточно привести лишь один аргумент к dynamic,
// дабы обозначить динамический контекст
public T Add(T A, T B) => (T)((dynamic)A + B);
```

И посмотрим, что получилось:

```
Calculator<int> calcInt = new Calculator<int>();
int resultInt = calcInt.Add(19, 23); // 42

Calculator<sbyte> calcSbyte = new Calculator<sbyte>();
sbyte resultSbyte = calcSbyte.Add(19, 23); // 42
```

Кажется, все чудесно работает!
Право, все же вынужден добавить бочку дегтя в эту ложку меда:

Помимо того, что разрешение динамического контекста съедает куда больше времени, нежели разрешение статического, так мы ведь не предусмотрели следующей вещи:

Кто нам мешает написать так?

```
Calculator<DateTime> calcDate = new Calculator<DateTime>();
DateTime resultDate = calcDate.Add(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
```

Как раз таки никто, так что код спокойно скомпилируется, экземпляр класса будет успешно создан, однако метод `Add` упадет со следующей ошибкой:

> **Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException**: Не удается применить оператор `+` к операндам типа `System.DateTime` и `System.DateTime`

Как уже упоминалось в самом вопросе, мы **не можем** ограничить `generic`-параметры определенным набором типов. Так что придется делать это вручную и в `runtime`:

```
public class Calculator<T>
{
    // Добавим классу статический инициализатор, который будет отвечать 
    // за проверку валидности типа

    // (Статический - дабы не проводить проверку несколько раз для одинаковых типов)
    static Calculator()
    {
        // Если тип не является одним из доступных, то сразу же выкинем ошибку,
        // дав тем самым конечному пользователю понять, что его 
        // действия неправомерны
        if (!new[] { typeof(sbyte), typeof(byte),
                    typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
                    typeof(int), typeof(uint),
                    typeof(long), typeof(ulong),
                    typeof(float), typeof(double)}.Contains(typeof(T)))
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Type `{typeof(T).FullName}` isn't supported!");
    }

    // Достаточно привести лишь один аргумент к dynamic,
    // дабы обозначить динамический контекст
    public T Add(T A, T B) => (T)((dynamic)A + B);           
}
```

###Плюсы:

- Мы избавились от дублирования кода
- Мы наконец добавили в код `generic`, чтобы для разных типов работали разные предопределенные методы

###Минусы:

- *"Чудесная"* скорость отработки динамического контекста
- Необходимость проверять допустимость используемого типа уже во время исполнения

---

## #2.0: Изменение контекста функции в зависимости от типа

Идея данного метода заключается в следующем:

Мы не можем просто так переназначить функции во время исполнения в духе:

```
public void A() => ...;
...
A = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
```

Однако мы можем переназначать переменные (в том числе и типов [делегатов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/))!

Мы можем создать внутреннее поле типа делегата, переназначать его в зависимости от ситуации, а уже публичный метод, будучи неизменным, как раз и будет его эксплуатировать:

```
public class Calculator<T>
{
    static Calculator()
    {
        // Инициализируем _add, исходя из типа generic-параметра
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(sbyte))
            _add = castFrom<sbyte>((x, y) => (sbyte)(x + y));
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
            _add = castFrom<byte>((x, y) => (byte)(x + y));
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(short))
            _add = castFrom<short>((x, y) => (short)(x + y));
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ushort))
            _add = castFrom<ushort>((x, y) => (ushort)(x + y));
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            _add = castFrom<int>((x, y) => x + y);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(uint))
            _add = castFrom<uint>((x, y) => x + y);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(long))
            _add = castFrom<long>((x, y) => x + y);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ulong))
            _add = castFrom<ulong>((x, y) => x + y);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            _add = castFrom<float>((x, y) => x + y);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
            _add = castFrom<double>((x, y) => x + y);
        else
            // Если тип не является ни одним из доступных, то выкинем ошибку 
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Type `{typeof(T).FullName}` isn't supported!");

        Func<T, T, T> castFrom<U>(Func<U, U, U> f) => (Func<T, T, T>)(object)f;
    }

    // Инструкция внутри _add будет проинициализированна
    // в зависимости от типа generic-параметра
    private static readonly Func<T, T, T> _add;

    // А вот инструкция в самой функции Add всегда одна - вызвать _add)
    public T Add(T A, T B) => _add(A, B);           
}
```

Этот метод стоило бы расположить в блоке про **"Дублирование кода"**, однако для многих он все же является менее очевидным, чем `dynamic`, да и тему можно развить, что показано в следующем блоке)

###Плюсы:

- Работать это будет куда быстрее, чем предыдущий метод с использованием динамического контекста

###Минусы:

- Мы опять злоупотребляем дублированием кода (опять же, можно совместить сей метод с кодогенерацией)
- Необходимость проверять допустимость используемого типа уже во время исполнения

<sub>Данный подход был первоначально описан в [ответе от VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662289/248572)</sub>

---

## #2.1: Expression:

С помощью класса [Expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) мы можем по узлам собрать нужное нам дерево выражений и скомпилировать его в делегат необходимой сигнатуры, используя при этом базовую идею предыдущего подхода:

```
public class Calculator<T>
{
    static Calculator()
    {
        // Эту проверку Вы уже наблюдали)
        if (!new[] { typeof(sbyte), typeof(byte),
            typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
            typeof(int), typeof(uint),
            typeof(long), typeof(ulong),
            typeof(float), typeof(double)}.Contains(typeof(T)))
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Type `{typeof(T).FullName}` isn't supported!");

        // Укажем параметры, испоьзуемые в функции
        ParameterExpression a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        ParameterExpression b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        // Создадим узел сложения заданных параметров
        BinaryExpression addition = Expression.Add(a, b);

        // Скомпилируем полученное дерево
        _add = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(addition, a, b).Compile();
    }

    // Инструкция внутри _add будет проинициализированна
    // в зависимости от типа generic-параметра
    private static readonly Func<T, T, T> _add;

    // А вот инструкция в самой функции Add всегда одна - вызвать _add)
    public T Add(T A, T B) => _add(A, B);
}
```

###Плюсы:

- Мы снова избавились от дублирования кода
- По скорости работы это приближено к не-`generic` реализациям)

###Минусы:

- Придется потратить немного ресурсов в `runtime` на создание метода
- Необходимость проверять допустимость используемого типа уже во время исполнения

<sub>Данный подход был первоначально описан в [ответе от Pavel Mayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562688/248572)</sub>

---

## #3.0: Векторизация

У `Microsoft` есть следующий прекрасный пакет - [System.Numerics.Vectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors), описание коиего гласит:

> Обеспечивает аппаратно-ускоренные числовые типы, подходящие для высокопроизводительной обработки и графических приложений.

В данном пакете нас интересует тип [Vector<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1), которой способен векторизовать входные данные, после чего мы можем применять к полученным векторам нужные нам арифметические операции!

Посмотрим на примере:

```
public class Calculator<T> where T : struct
{
    static Calculator()
    {
        // Эту проверку Вы уже наблюдали)
        if (!new[] { typeof(sbyte), typeof(byte),
                typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
                typeof(int), typeof(uint),
                typeof(long), typeof(ulong),
                typeof(float), typeof(double)}.Contains(typeof(T)))
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Type `{typeof(T).FullName}` isn't supported!");
    }

    // Создадим векторы на основе заданных значений,
    // после чего сложим их и вернем 0-вое измерение
    // результирующего вектора
    public T Add(T A, T B) => (new Vector<T>(A) + new Vector<T>(B))[0];
}
```

###Плюсы:

- Никакого дублирования кода
- Высокая производительность (в некоторых тестах векторизация показывает себя даже лучше нативного кода! Какие операции пройдут быстрее - смотрите в [данной табличке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1#remarks))

###Минусы:

- Необходимость установки дополнительного `nuget`-пакета
- Необходимость проверять допустимость используемого типа уже во время исполнения

<sub>Данный подход был первоначально описан в [ответе от VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562580/248572)</sub>

---

## #4.0: IL позволит Вам то, чего не позволит C#!

Как известно, код любого `.NET`-языка транслируется в [IL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)-код. Этот факт мы и будем использовать)

Напишем такой вот код:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = a + b;
```

Просмотрев `IL`-код, созданный для данной цепочки выражений, мы увидим нечто такое:

```
ldc.i4.2    
stloc a
ldc.i4.3    
stloc b
ldloc a
ldloc b
add         
stloc c
```

*(Код примерный, таким он, конечно, не будет. Приведен он в таком виде для ясности происходящего)*

Что же отвечает за сложение двух чисел типа `int`? 
Стандартная инструкция `add`)

Перепишем код:

```
double a = 2;
double b = 3;
double c = a + b;
```

Теперь `IL` будет таковым:

```
ldc.r8 2
stloc a
ldc.r8 3
stloc b
ldloc a
ldloc b
add         
stloc c
```

Что изменилось? Только инструкция ***l**oa**dc**onstant*, инструкция же сложения так и осталось на своем законном месте)

Я веду к тому, что на уровне `IL` **одна и та же** инструкция `add` спокойненько обрабатывает сложение экземпляров типов `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double`)
А ведь это именно то, что нам нужно!

(К слову, это верно и для инструкций `sub`, `mul`, `div`, `rem`. Подробный лист инструкций `IL` с описанием [найдете здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions))

Добавим к проекту файл `Calc.il`, используя расширение [ILSupport](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ins0mniaque.ILSupport), после чего запишем туда следующий код:

```
.class Calc.Calculator`1<T>
{
    .method public !T Add(!T, !T) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 2
        ldarg.0     // Кладем на стек нулевой аргумент
        ldarg.1     // Кладем на стек первый аргумент
        add         // Складываем их
        ret         // Возвращаем результат
    }
}
```

На `C#` же проделаем следующие манипуляции с классом:

```
public class Calculator<T>
{
    static Calculator()
    {
        // Эту проверку Вы уже наблюдали)
        if (!new[] { typeof(sbyte), typeof(byte),
                typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
                typeof(int), typeof(uint),
                typeof(long), typeof(ulong),
                typeof(float), typeof(double)}.Contains(typeof(T)))
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Type `{typeof(T).FullName}` isn't supported!");
    }

    // Сообщаем, что метод реализован где-то в другом месте
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef)]
    public extern T Add(T A, T B);
}
```

Вот и готово! Скомпилировав проект, мы получим класс, который способен работать с любым стандартным числовым типом)

###Плюсы:

- Никакого дублирования кода
- Не нужно тратить времени и прочих ресурсов на создание метода в `runtime`
- Высокая производительность, совпадающая с таковой нативного кода (ибо это он по сути и есть))

###Минусы:

- Для человека, который не знаком с `IL`, решение может показаться сложным
- Необходимо настроить проект на *"сожительство"* `C#` и `IL`
- Необходимость проверять допустимость используемого типа уже во время исполнения

<sub>Данный подход был первоначально описан в [ответе от Kir_Antipov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/894125/248572)</sub>

---

Надеюсь, один из предложенных в данном ответе методов помог решить Вам указанную задачу)

А пока у меня есть 2 большие просьбы:

0. Не забывайте благодарить авторов оригинальных ответов (помимо своего решения я собрал в данном ответе и идеи других участников сообщества, приведя на них ссылки)
1. Если у Вас есть еще идеи по решению данной задачи/по исправлению данного ответа - пишите комментарии! Буду безумно рад выслушать Ваше мнение)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85144/discussion-on-answer-by-kir-antipov-------).

Comment: Надо еще отметить, что решение, основанное на Expressions, прилично ускоряется при применении к алгоритму целиком вместо элементарных операций вроде сложения и вычитания.

Comment: Кроме того, решения через Expressions или dynamic работают с любыми типами где есть оператор сложения, в отличии от решений через IL и кодогенерацию.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: ну, на IL я могу написать метод, который будет работать и с теми типами, у которых определён статический `op_Addition`, и с остальными) Но в вопросе мы говорим про числа

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: (По поводу комментариев в чате) Непонятно, почему упадёт в сборщике мусора. По идее, должно упасть при первом же использовании с неправильным типом.

Comment: @VladD: если запихнуть ту часть, в которой инициализируемый тип упадёт с ошибкой (`ErrorClass e; try { e = new ErrorClass(); // Ошибка статической инициализации здесь } catch { }`), то позже приложение упадёт во время сборки мусора (работает до .NET 4.0)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Интересно, не знал! Сейчас попробую оттестировать это.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: У меня вот такое на свежем .NET не падает: https://pastebin.com/4SkS5kkY. И на 4.0 вроде тоже.

Comment: @VladD: простите, пожалуйста, совсем закопался в делах. Добавьте в свой класс любой финализатор, хоть пустой (`~ErrorClass() { }`), а также смените таргетинг на `.NET 3.5` (ибо как раз в `4.0` сборщик претерпел некоторые изменения). Тогда Вы и увидите (не)ожидаемое падение

Comment: @VladD: я волнуюсь вот за что: до 4.0 мусорщик работал в основном потоке приложения, временно приостанавливая процесс выполнения всего и всея, быстренько подчищая все сущее. Так что все ошибки при сборке мусора будут сыпаться в основной поток, прерывая процесс выполнения программы (что мы и наблюдаем: сборщик безо всяких проверок вызывает финализатор объекта, чей тип не был статически инициализирован). С 4.0 мусорщик работает параллельно с нашим кодом (если я правильно внимал changelog'y), так что его ошибки (в теории) могут угаснуть где-то "не у нас", не сломав приложение, но нарушив

Comment: ... правильную работу сборщика мусора

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Проблему воспроизвёл, видимо, нужно делать, как [тут](http://rsdn.org/forum/dotnet/2051743), или использовать статическую фабрику. Хотя, неправильное использование всё равно фатальный баг, так что может быть и ничего не надо делать.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: А интересно, что происходит в .NET 4.0+? GC не останавливается? Нужно ли для старших версий .NET исправлять что-либо?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Вроде бы работает: https://pastebin.com/VF5WAzck

Comment: @VladD: вот и я за это переживал) Действительно, сейчас проверим

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Решение #4.0 не пройдёт для типа `decimal` по идее, т. к. у него не нативная операция сложения, а оператор `op_Addition`.

Comment: @VladD: таки я знаю) Как видите, в вопросе я его не указывал хД

Answer (score 4):

Мне нравятся подходы 0.0 и 0.1 из предыдущего ответа, но дублирование кода я бы сделал по-другому принципу, я бы вынес интерфейс `ICalculator<T>`:

```
public interface ICalculator<T>
{
    T Add(T a, T b);
    T Sub(T a, T b);
    T Mul(T a, T b);
    T Div(T a, T b);
    T Mod(T a, T b);
}

public class IntCalculator : ICalculator<int>
{        
    public int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;
    public int Sub(int a, int b) => a - b;
    public int Mul(int a, int b) => a * b;
    public int Div(int a, int b) => a / b;
    public int Mod(int a, int b) => a % b;
}
```

Потребуется реализовать `ICalculator<T>` для каждого типа с которым вы хотите работать, они не обязательно должны быть числами. Такой подход будет гораздо лучше если вы используете Dependency Injection, вы сможете передавать `ICalculator<T>` в класс где он требуется. Ну и напоследок - реализация может быть либо такой, либо можно создать универсальную с dynamic или IL.

Comment: Согласен с Вами) В «дублировании» я больше говорил о подходе, нежели о том, как это реально стоит делать) Весь мой ответ состоит из подходов, которые уже можно переделать под себя.

Answer (score 4):

**Обновлено:** В .NET 7 появилась встроенная поддержка [Generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math), так что приведенные в данной теме ухищрения становятся не нужны. Чтобы создать метод, принимающий любое число, нужно ограничить обобщенный тип интерфейсом INumber:

```
static T Add<T>(T x, T y) where T : INumber<T>
{
    return x + y;
}
```

---

Ответ для предыдущих версий:

Все числовые типы объединяет то, что они являются структурами и реализуют интерфейс IComparable. С этим ограничением уже можно отсечь много неподходящих типов на этапе компиляции. Не нужно использовать статические конструкторы для "валидации", они предназначены для инициализации глобального состояния, и класс, единственная задача которого - арифметические операции, вообще не должен их иметь. Проверяйте перед вычислением (или компиляцией выражения), это намного более логично.

Что касается алгоритма, есть еще один способ, который лежит на поверхности: это простой обобщенный метод с несколькими ветками в условном операторе. Может показаться, что веток будет слишком много, но на самом деле, операции сложения для многих типов по сути одинаковы и отличаются только типом, к которому приводится конечный результат. Например, операцию сложения на целом типе можно представить как операцию сложения на Decimal с последующим "сужающим" приведением к целому типу (Decimal позволяет представить все значения любых целых типов и еще оставляет некоторый запас для обработки переполнений). Аналогично, сложение на типе float можно представить как сложение на типе double с последующим преобразованием результата.

Весь набор числовых типов можно разделить на три группы:

1. **Беззнаковые целые.** Для них формула преобразования из Decimal в конкретный тип будет выглядеть так:

> y = x % 2  <sup>n</sup>

где n - размер типа в битах.

(Остаток от деления тут появляется, так как по умолчанию у нас unchecked-контекст, и переполнения не генерируют ошибку, а просто обрезаются по границе типа.)

2. **Знаковые целые.** Для них минимальное значение равно **- 0.5 * 2  <sup>n</sup>**, а максимальное **0.5 * 2  <sup>n</sup> - 1**. Пользуясь этим, можно вывести формулу перевода:

> y = (x + 2  <sup>n</sup> * 1.5) % 2  <sup>n</sup> - 0.5 * 2  <sup>n</sup>

На самом деле, формула может выглядеть по разному, но для отлова переполнений подходит именно такой вид.

3. **С плавающей точкой.** Ну, тут все просто, формула не нужна, так как преобразование из double в float это просто обрезка "знаков после запятой".

Реализовать это можно так:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Calculator<T> where T : struct,IComparable
    {
        static bool IsSignedInteger(Type t)
        {
            return (t == typeof(sbyte) || t == typeof(short) || t == typeof(int) || t == typeof(long));
        }

        static bool IsUnsignedInteger(Type t)
        {
            return (t == typeof(byte) || t == typeof(ushort) || t == typeof(uint) || t == typeof(ulong));
        }

        static bool IsReal(Type t)
        {
            return (t == typeof(float) || t == typeof(double));
        }

        //преобразует значение из Decimal в целевой целочисленный тип
        public static T FromDecimal(decimal val)
        {
            //вычисляем размер типа
            int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

            //вычисляем количество элементов в целевом множестве
            decimal capacity = (size < 8) ? (1L << (size * 8)) : ((decimal)UInt64.MaxValue + 1);

            //отображаем элемент на целевое множество
            decimal res;

            if (IsUnsignedInteger(typeof(T)))
            {
                res = (val) % (capacity);
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(res, typeof(T));
            }
            else if (IsSignedInteger(typeof(T)))
            {    
                res = (val + capacity * 1.5M) % (capacity) - capacity * 0.5M;    
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(res, typeof(T));
            }
            else throw new NotSupportedException(typeof(T).ToString() + " is not integer type");
        }

        //непосредственно сложение
        public static T Add(T A, T B)
        {
            if (IsSignedInteger(typeof(T)) || IsUnsignedInteger(typeof(T)))
            {
                return FromDecimal(Convert.ToDecimal(A) + Convert.ToDecimal(B));
            }
            else if (IsReal(typeof(T)))
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Convert.ToDouble(A) + Convert.ToDouble(B), typeof(T));
            }
            else throw new NotSupportedException(typeof(T).ToString() + " is not supported, because it is not numeric type");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            unchecked
            {
                //тест сложения целых чисел
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Calculator<int>.Add(1000, 222), (1000 + 222));
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Calculator<byte>.Add(200, 200), (byte)(200 + 200));
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Calculator<sbyte>.Add(100, 100), (sbyte)(100 + 100));                        
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Calculator<long>.Add(long.MinValue, -1), (long)(long.MinValue - 1));

                //тест сложения с плавающей точкой    
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Calculator<float>.Add((float)Math.PI, 2.2f), (float)Math.PI + 2.2f);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Calculator<double>.Add(Math.PI, 2.2), Math.PI + 2.2);
                
                //этот код выдаст исключение...                
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}", Calculator<DateTime>.Add(DateTime.Now, new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)));
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}", Calculator<bool>.Add(true, true));

                //а этот - не скомпилируется
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}", Calculator<string>.Add("Саша", "Маша"));
                
            } 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }              
    }
}
```

Если наплевать на переполнения, то код можно значительно упростить.

Comment: Любопытно, но операции с `decimal` существенно менее эффективны, чем с примитивными типами. Хотя это, наверное, обгонит `dynamic`.