# Ограничение обобщения любым типом данных числа

Tags: c#, функции, структуры, типы-данных, синтаксис

Возможно ли в C# ограничить обобщение функции исключительно числами? Например, я хочу создать структуру Bounds, которая будет поддерживать минимальную и максимальную границу чего-либо. Границы должны быть **только** числами, однако они могут быть и `int`, и `float`, и `double`, и так далее.

У меня была идея реализовать это через обобщения структуры и ограничения этого обобщения только данными типами подобным образом:

```
struct Bounds<T> where T: int, float, double {
    T Min, Max;
    // Далее можно будет, например реализовать метод проверки числа в границах:
    bool isInBounds (T num)
        => num >= Min && num <= Max;
}
```

Однако подобная реализация выдает ошибку: `"int" не является допустимым ограничением.`
Похоже, ограничением обобщения структуры вообще быть не могут!
Если это не так, то как возможно ввести подобное ограничение?
Если это так, то есть ли более красивый способ ввести подобное ограничение, кроме как делать что-то подобное:

```
public struct Bounds <T> {
    T Min, Max;

    public Bounds<T> (T min, T max) {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int) || typeof(T) == typeof(float) || ...) {
            Min = min;
            ...
        }
        else 
            throw new Exception(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Наиболее близко ограничение [unmanaged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types)

Comment: Если цель - _сравнение_ обобщённых типов, то следует задать в качестве ограничения интерфейс `IComparable`.

Comment: как насчет where T : IComparable<T>

Comment: пока такого сделать нельзя.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это зависит от того, какие операции именно вы хотите поддерживать.

На текущий момент полноценной поддержки интерфейса наподобие `INumeric` нет по той причине, что этот интерфейс нечем наполнить: в C# нету покамест поддержки операторов наподобие `+` или `<` в интерфейсах. Однако, работа в этом направлении ведётся, и с эволюцией языка такая возможность появится. Вот тут [[1]](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4436), [[2]](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/205) ведётся работа в этом направлении, пока лишь на уровне дизайна и понимания того, как это должно выглядеть.

Когда такой вот интерфейс `INumeric` появится, вы сможете использовать его как generic constraint, и при этом пользоваться операциями наподобие сложения и сравнения.

---

Вы можете в принципе перенести проверку времени *выполнения* в статический конструктор:

```
struct Bounds<T>
{
    static Bounds()
    {
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(int) &&
            typeof(T) != typeof(double) &&
            typeof(T) != typeof(float))
           throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Bounds<> can be instantiated only with types int, double, float");
    }
}
```

тогда она не будет отнимать времени на каждой инстанциации `Bounds<T>`.

Если вам нужна лишь часть функциональности и не особо важен красивый синтаксис, можно подумать о реализации вручную, но может пострадать эффективность. Вот есть примеры:

- [Как написать метод/класс, который бы одинаково работал со всеми числовыми типами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/899928/10105)
- [C# как создать класс который бы одинаково работал с int и double?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662148/10105)
- [Реализация Матрицы C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562575/10105)

---

Исходя из названия `Bounds`, как правильно советуют в комментариях, вам может быть достаточно одного лишь `IComparable<T>`. В этом случае ограничение числовыми типами не имеет особенного смысла, и вы можете просто написать

```
struct Bounds<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T Min, Max;
    static Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default; // использует IComparable<T>

    bool isInBounds (T num)
        => comparer.Compare(num, Min) >= 0 && comparer.Compare(num, Max) <= 0;
}
```

Если вам нужны более продвинутые операции, вы можете либо воспользоваться кодом из ответов, упомянутых ранее, либо взять готовую реализацию в nuget-пакете [Genumerics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Genumerics/):

```
using Genumerics;

struct Bounds<T>
{
    T Min, Max;
    public static Bounds<T> FromMidpointAndHalfWidth(T midpoint, T halfwidth)
    {
        if (Number.LessThan(halfwidth, Number.Zero<T>()))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(halfwidth),
                                                  "Width should be not negative");
        return new Bounds<T>()
        {
            Min = Number.Subtract(midpoint, halfwidth),
            Max = Number.Add(midpoint, halfwidth)
        };
    }

    public bool IsInBounds(T num) =>
        Number.GreaterThanOrEqual(num, Min) && Number.LessThanOrEqual(num, Max);
}
```

Comment: Что ж, может когда-нибудь появится такая возможность действительно, а пока спасибо:)

Comment: @МаксимФисман: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, к C# 11 будет возможно и «прямое» решение.