# Обобщения C# - проблема с перемножением матрицы, невозможно преобразовать тип 'double' в тип 'Т'

Tags: c#, ооп, матрицы

Возникла пара ошибок с обобщениями. Работаю с матрицей, в которую нужно записывать любой тип; реализовать умножение, суммирование, вычитание и т.д. Возникла проблема с умножением матрицы на `double`; генерация матрицы осуществляется путем случайного заполнения числами типа `int`. Как реализовать заполнение только для определенного типа? Или же по-особенному переопределять арифметические операции для определенных типов?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ISMClasses2
{
    class Matrix<T>
    {
        protected T[,] Matr;
        public int RowCount {get{ return Matr.GetLength(0);}}
        public int ColCount { get { return Matr.GetLength(1);}}
        static int generator=10;

        public Matrix(int n)
        {
            Matr = new T[n, n];
            generator += 10;
        }

        public Matrix(int n, int m)
        {
            Matr = new T[n, m];
            generator += 10;
        }

        public void GenerateMatrix()
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ColCount; j++)
                {
                    Matr[i,j]=(random.Next(generator, 100));
                }
            }
        }

        public Fraction this[int i, int j]
        {
            set { Matr[i, j] = value; }
            get { return Matr[i, j]; }
        }

        public static Matrix<T> operator +(Matrix<T>matrix1, Matrix<T>matrix2)
        {
            if (matrix2 == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(matrix2));
            }

            Matrix<T> summed = new Matrix<T>(matrix1.RowCount,matrix1.ColCount);
            if (matrix1.RowCount == matrix2.RowCount && matrix1.ColCount == matrix2.ColCount)
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.RowCount; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.ColCount; j++)
                        summed[i, j] = matrix1[i, j] + matrix2[i, j];
            else
                throw new Exception("Error...");
            return summed;
        }

        public static Matrix<T> operator -(Matrix<T> matrix1, Matrix<T> matrix2)
        {
            Matrix<T> subtract = new Matrix<T>(matrix1.RowCount, matrix1.ColCount);
            if (matrix1.RowCount == matrix2.RowCount && matrix1.ColCount == matrix2.ColCount)
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.RowCount; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.ColCount; j++)
                        subtract[i, j] = matrix1[i, j] - matrix2[i, j];
            else
                throw new Exception("Error...");
            return subtract;
        }

        public static Matrix<T> operator *(Matrix<T> matrix1, Matrix<T> matrix2)
        {
            Matrix<T> matrix=new Matrix<T>(matrix1.RowCount,matrix2.ColCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.RowCount;i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.ColCount;j++)
                    matrix[i, j] = 0;
            if(matrix1.ColCount==matrix2.RowCount)
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.RowCount; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix2.ColCount; j++)
                    {
                        for (int m1 = 0; m1 < matrix1.ColCount; m1++)
                            matrix[i, j] += matrix1[i, m1] * matrix2[m1, j];
                    }
            return matrix;
        }

        double DoubleMatrixDeterminant(Matrix<T> matr2)
        {
            return ((matr2[0, 0] * matr2[1, 1]) - (matr2[0, 1] * matr2[1, 0]));
        }

        public double determinant(int n)
        {
                Matrix<T> mtr = new Matrix<T>(RowCount - 1);
                double det = 0;
                 int j2 = 0;
            if (RowCount > 2)
            {

                for (int j1 = 0; j1 < RowCount; j1++)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < RowCount; i++)//large matrix
                    {
                        j2 = 0;
                        for (int j = 0; j < RowCount; j++)
                        {
                            if (j == j1)
                                continue;
                            mtr.Matr[i - 1, j2] = Matr[i, j];
                            j2++;
                        }
                    }
                    det += Matr[0,j1] * Math.Pow(-1, 1 + j1) * -(mtr.determinant(n-1));
                }
                    return det;
            }
            else
            {
               return DoubleMatrixDeterminant(this);
            }
        }

        private static int ToInteger(double Matr)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(Matr);
        }

        public static implicit operator string(Matrix<T> matrix)
        {
            string matr="";
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.ColCount; j++)
                    matr += matrix[i,j]+" ";
                matr += Environment.NewLine;
            }
            return matr;
        }

        public Matrix<T> Transposed(Matrix<T> matr)
        {
            Matrix<T> matrix = new Matrix<T>(matr.ColCount, matr.RowCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.ColCount; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i,j] = matr[j, i];
                }
            }
            return matrix;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Уже было, найдите дубликат, кто-нибудь!

Comment: @VladD, Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Реализация Матрицы C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562575/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-c)

Comment: Добавил (dynamic) перед значением - все работает

Comment: @AshenOne, вопросы, помеченные дубликатами, намеренно не удяляются автоматически, в отличие от многих других закрытых вопросов, поскольку разная формулировка помогает найти нужный вопрос по большему числу поисковых запросов. Пожалуйта, не надо их удалять.